# Get group by records from many to many relationship table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, many-to-many, entity-framework-6

I have 3 tables, `Person` | `Book` | `PersonBook`
`PersonBook` table is relaton table between `Person` and `Book`

```
Person          Book                    PersonBooks
Id   Name       Id     Name             Id   PersonId   BookId
1    rick        1      SQL              1     1          1
2    phil        2      Asp.Net          2     1          3
3    scott       3      MySql            3     2          4 
                 4      C#               4     3          2
                                         5     3          3
                                         6     3          4
```

I want to get the person who read book id 2, 3, 4. therefore result should be 3.

#### Whats have i tried

I manage to write sql query to get the result. but i want Linq query for this.
My sql query is

```
SELECT DISTINCT(PersonId) From PersonBooks
WHERE BookId IN (2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY PersonId
HAVING COUNT (*) = 3
```

sql query if working fine. but i want to use linq query for this. Any help will be appriciated

#### Update

This query works for me but i don't think it is optimized. can anyone help me to optimize this query.

```
from p in Context.Book where (Context.PersonBooks.Where(x => personIds.Contains(x.PersonId))
    .GroupBy(x => x.BookId)
    .Where(x=>x.Count() == personIds.Count)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
    .Select(x => x.Key).ToList()).Contains(p.BookId) select p;
```

Comment: I don't think your query is working fine, you need FROM and you don't need Distinct.

Comment: @Tim3880 sorry typo error :)

Comment: @Tim3880 actually i need distinct this is not original table just demo data without distinct i'mm getting error. the original tables contains many other columns also.

Answer (score 4):

```
var person = (from p in PersonBooks
                  join b in Book on p.BookId equals b.BookId
                  where b.BookId  IN (2, 3, 4)
                  select new { p.PersonId});
```

Comment: You don't need `Book` because `PersonBook` already has `BookId`. Also, `IN` doesn't exist in LINQ syntax.

Comment: yea I overlooked that.Thanks @GertArnold

Answer (score 2):

As usual, people jump to join syntax in LINQ, but you should definitely use navigation properties:

```
var ids = new[] { 2, 3, 4 };
var persons = from p in db.Persons
              where p.PersonBooks.All(pb => ids.Contains(pb.BookId))
                 && p.PersonBooks.Count() == 3
              select p;
```

This translates into an EXIST clause, so you don't need `Distinct` any more. It also returns `Person`s, as you required, not just Ids.

By the way, if you want persons that read *at least one* (not all) books, you can replace `All` by `Any`.

Comment: it is not working showing all book which are read by any of selected ids.

Comment: yes i specify this in my question, I want person who read all books not atleast one.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you post the generated SQL (using the `All` statement) into your question?

Comment: Well, now the question is different. I modified my query so it includes the count. Now it selects persons that read all books and not only some books in `ids`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
from bp in BookPerson
join p in person on p.personId== bp.personId
join b in books on b.bookId == bp.bookId
where b.bookId = 1 && b.bookId = 2 && b.bookId = 3
group p by bp.personId into p
select new {g.personId};
```

Comment: You don't need the joins. You can doe everything with `PersonBook` alone. Note that `b.bookId = 1 && b.bookId = 2 && b.bookId = 3` is never `true`. And: `group ... into p` is a type, and the grouping (`g`) doesn't have a `personId`.